# MongoDB - Can I limit my query results to one record/user/day?

Tags: mongodb, group-by

I have a table of activities of two types (A and B).  These activities are generated by users.  What I want to do is grab the 20 most recent activities, but for the B activities, only include the first activity created by a user for that day.  So if a user creates 4 A activities and 4 B activities in a single day, it would show all 4 A activities, but only the first B activity created.  If they created the same amount of activities again the next day, the query would show all 8 A activities, but only 2 B activities.

My current approach is to get the list of B activities with a group by clause, grouping on the date and the user.  I have that query working:

```
db.runCommand({    
  group: {
    ns: 'activities',
    $keyf: function(doc) {
      var created = doc._id.getTimestamp();
      created.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      return { created: created, user: doc.user.id }
    },
    $reduce: function( curr, result ) { 
      // We only need the first activity of the day, but we can't sort (can we?)
      var earliestSoFar = result.date || new Date();

      if (earliestSoFar > curr._id.getTimestamp()) {
        result.id = curr._id;
        result.date = curr._id.getTimestamp();
      }
    },
    cond: {
      "type" : "B"
    },
    initial: {}
  }
})
```

I was thinking I could then get the id's from that result collection and run a final query of the form:

```
.find({ $or: [
  { type: 'A' },
  { _id: { $in: getListOfIdsFromGroupQuery() }}
]}).limit(20);
```

I believe this will give me the results I want, but what I'm afraid of is:

1. The group query will return me a list of every first B activity/user/day.  I'm only showing 20 activities at a time, so I only care about the 20 most recent B activities (at most, since i'm showing 20 A & B combined).  This seems really wasteful.
2. On the first query, I can trim the array that I pass to $in down to 20 ids.  However, because the user can view the next page, I have to pass in 40 ids for the 2nd page, 60 for the 3rd page, etc.  By the 10th page, my $in query is looking for 200 records.  Not sure if this is a problem, but it worries me.

Is there a better way to approach this?  Hopefully it's clear, I know it's kind of a confusing situation.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe you could have an array of activities for each user, instead of storing them as separate documents. So you would do a "db.collection.update({user:"Bob"},{$push:{activityTypeB:{$each:["Skates"],$slice:-20}}})" or similar but I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you require. All the best.

Comment: Unfortunately it's too late to change the Schema of the collection.